# Is the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform (Roslyn compiler) useful in Web API 2 projects?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, roslyn

I understand that the *Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform* package is useful in WebForms and MVC applications that have compilable view objects. Web API 2 does not have such compilable views. Is this compiler package useful with Web API 2 applications?